# ddrescue restore image to same disk

Tags: linux, hard-drive, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, ddrescue

Our 4TB drive was failing. I unmounted the principal partition and ran `ddrescue /dev/sdb1 /work2/timhay01/work.img /home/timhay01/work_backup.log --try-again --force --verbose` where /work2/ is mounted on a new 6TB drive. 99.9% of the partition was rescued.

Now I want to restore the contents of the disk image to the same 6TB drive. The issue is that while the image is present there is only 2TB free space remaining. Is there an automatic way to achieve this without resorting to another disk?

Comment: Was that a system disk? Which filesystem, was there LVM? Do you know the amount of data which was on failing disk? What do you wan't to achieve? If it's just about accessing filesystem, you can mount recovered image in place (`losetup`, and `mount` loop device).